# Java crashes when trying to open a .jar

Tags: java, crash

I have a code that installs database pieces through a .jar file. A buddy of mine was installing the same code on the same OS on a different machine, and it installed fine. Mine crashed after loading java.lang.ProcessImpl, but I can't figure out why. I have attached the next few lines of the log file from my buddy's computer, which worked, starting at the last line my log outputs. I'm pretty new at messing with jars or java in general, so I'm not even sure what I can check to figure out this problem. Any helpful thoughts from the great Stack community? Is there another way to open .jar files, maybe through netbeans?

```
  //Here is the last line my computer runs. After this, it crashes out.
  [Loaded java.lang.ProcessImpl from C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\lib\rt.jar]
  [Loaded java.lang.ProcessImpl$2 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\lib\rt.jar]
  [Loaded com.izforge.izpack.uninstaller.SelfModifier$StreamProxy from file:/D:/Scale/scale-6.2-data-setup.jar]
```

Answer (score 0):

Jar files are just zip files. You're on a windows machine so you can just change the extension and double click to open if you want to extract it and see what's in it.

To see what's really going on, we'd need to see the WHOLE log including the dump. My guess is that you might have a JRE/JDK conflict where it's trying to load the jars of one version with another. Depending on the version difference that could result in a JVM crash.

Comment: I can include the full log, but it's some 1800 lines. From other things I've read, it looks like a JRE/JDK conflict, but I've uninstalled all JREs/JDKs from my system and re-installed it from the JDK. I've even tried JDK version 7, 8, and 9, doing a full uninstall in between each version. My buddy downloaded the JRE first, then the JDK after, which I haven't tried, but it shouldn't matter because the JDK installs the JRE, right?

Anyway, how should I do the log file? Is there a more important part, or should I try to dump the whole thing? If I could attach files, I'd just do that.